# TinyMCE not display webpage content in IE8 browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, tinymce, text-editor

While I am pasting a content from a webpage, the `tinymce` editor in IE8 doesn't display the content.

Hi, i am adding the image that I got. [image]

**My issue is**
1.I have copy content from the webpage http://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH02/ats/careers/requisition.jsp?org=TRAILERPARK&cws=1&rid=148
and try to paste in to my tinymce editor which is open in Ie8..
2.the result is shown as like in the image as red box

Comment: how is your tinymce configured? can you show us, what text/code you pasted? is there a live example or at least a tinymce fiddle where we can see what happens?

Comment: i had pasted webpage content..copiying and pasteing it in the editor..

Comment: use the ' none' as the mode and default as the theme

Comment: sorry, that doesn't help much

Comment: i had pasted the text from
http://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH02/ats/careers/requisition.jsp?org=TRAILERPARK&cws=1&rid=148

Comment: please paste the contents into tinymce editor opened in Ie8 browser

Comment: works for me. you should exactly describe what you tried and what you want + the result

Comment: Hi,.copy the contents from http://ch.tbe.taleo.net/CH02/ats/careers/requisition.jsp?org=TRAILERPARK&cws=1&rid=148 
try to paste into tinymce editor job desription field and the browser should be Ie8.

4.noting will get displayed,the page get crashed

Comment: my acual result is
Page crashes with only displayes lines.
my expected result is
The tinymce editor will shows the copied content

Comment: I have work the tinymce in all other browser except IE8

Comment: can you add a screen image of the content after you inserted it?

Comment: Please copy and paste the contents from the site i have given...all others are working fine

Comment: i want to make sure that what i see is the same what you see - so please add an image of your screen

Comment: Hi,I had updated my question..please check

Comment: +1 thx for the image, which tinymce version are you using? (i do not get this kind of result with IE8 (IE-8 modus from IE9) )

Comment: i am using tinymce version 3.5.8.And please not that the compatibility mode is working fine.
The only problem is it is not working in Ie8 browser not the compatible mode

Comment: hi,please help me on this issue

Comment: As I know, higher version of tinymce has some problem with lower IE version, you can search the related docs on official site. So I suggest you to detect the IE version and turn on compatible mode in code.

Answer (score 1):

Refere to [Adding new fonts to TinyMCE font options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170758/adding-new-fonts-to-tinymce-font-options)

the site you're copying from uses (see the source):

```
@font-face
    {
        font-family: "Museo Slab W01 1000";
        src: url("http://www.trailerpark.com/Fonts/ee02ec61-b42e-49bb-9942-0793380267f5.eot?iefix");
        src:
            url("http://www.trailerpark.com/Fonts/f6e64e68-be62-481f-bcf3-923028fc62e0.svg#f6e64e68-be62-481f-bcf3-923028fc62e0") format("svg"),
            url("http://www.trailerpark.com/Fonts/b6bcb198-882f-4f57-a02c-07e8155aab5f.woff") format("woff"),
            url("http://www.trailerpark.com/Fonts/cfa01f25-bb4c-4a09-8ba3-8afafcbb3508.ttf") format("truetype");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method type :  encoding : "raw"

function exilTinyMCEInit(args) {

```
tinyMCE.init({
            mode : "exact",
            theme : "advanced",
            plugins : "paste",
            elements : args,
            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,bullist,numlist,undo,redo",
            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "center",
            theme_advanced_resizing : false,
            onchange_callback : "exilTinyMCEOnChangeHandler",
            encoding : "raw",
            setup : function(ed) {
                var curElement = P2.getFieldObject(ed.id);
                if (curElement.disabled || curElement.readOnly) {
                    ed.settings.readonly = true;
                } else {
                    ed.settings.readonly = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

}