# TinyMCE, new font added can't be selected

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I've added a new font with theme_advanced_fonts on tinyMCE, but it doesn't works.

All others fonts works, I can select it and see result but with the new font, if text is in this font, I see good result but I can select this font in tinyMCE.

My code is :

```
$('.screen-textarea').tinymce({
                        script_url : '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                        mode : "textareas",
                        theme : "advanced",
                        plugins : "style,inlinepopups",

                        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,forecolor,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "bottom",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
                        theme_advanced_fonts : "ChildsPlay=ChildsPlay;"+"Academy Engraved LET=Academy Engraved LET;"+"American Typewriter=American Typewriter;"+"Arial=Arial;"+"Bradley Hand=Bradley Hand;"+"Chalkduster=Chalkduster;"+"Copperplate=Copperplate;"+"Courier=Courier;"+"Futura=Futura;"+"Georgia=Georgia;"+"Helvetica Neue=Helvetica Neue;"+"Marker Felt=Marker Felt;"+"Noteworthy=Noteworthy;"+"Optima=Optima;"+"Papyrus=Papyrus;"+"Party LET=Party LET;"+"Snell Roundhand=Snell Roundhand;"+"Times New Roman=Times New Roman;"+"Verdana=Verdana;"+"Sanchez=Sanchez;",
                        theme_advanced_font_sizes : "12px,15px,18px,22px,25px,29px,35px,41px,48px,51px,59px,66px,73px,78px,84px,88px,90px",
                        theme_advanced_text_colors : "C2C2C2,FFFFFF,000000,1c2977"
                    });
```

Font doesn't works is Sanchez. I've this font on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at other posts on this kind of issue, I have the impression that the semi-colon ";" at the end of your font list should not be there - it should end ......+"Sanchez=Sanchez" not ......+"Sanchez=Sanchez;"

I am no expert on this stuff, but have been looking around for another issue and came across this at [Adding new fonts to TinyMCE font options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170758/adding-new-fonts-to-tinymce-font-options?rq=1)

Hope this isn't irrelevant and might help

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this font is not loaded in your editors iframe.
In order to load this font add the following code (modified to your needs) using the content_css tinymce config param.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "your_font";
    font-style:  normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("http://your_server/font_directory/your_font.ttf");
}
```